# Javascript negative float number calculation

Tags: javascript, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript’s Floating-Point Math Broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken)

In Javascript, how do I compute the result of `23668-23671.88` to `-3.88` instead of `-3.8800000000010186` ?

I don't want any rounding, since if I use a windows calc, the result is -3.88.

Is it possible?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Quite interesting question! Has anyone the reason why JS doesn't return -3.88?

Comment: It's not possible. Windows calculator does the rounding.

Comment: becoz the calculation is binary?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Are you sure? I would not put it beyond Windows calculator to use BigDecimals where it makes sense.

Comment: @Thilo I guess that MsCalc is more ancient than BigDecimals.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to round, then you need some way of determining the precision of the variables in your expression and apply that precision to the result of the expression. Unfortunately, JavaScript does not have a way to determine the precision of floats.

However, there is a simple 'hacky' way you can accomplish this:

http://jsfiddle.net/SjxCY/2/

```
var num = 2.383;
var precision = (num+'').split('.')[1].length;
var final = (234234-num).toFixed(precision);
alert(final);
```

It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on `2.383+""` being `"2.383"`

Comment: I'm not saying it's not always a string. I'm saying it might be longer than expected.

Comment: I've tested cross-browser. Do you have any examples?

Comment: What about performing operations other than addition/substraction? (num * 0,5).toFixed(precision) will cut off the last number.

Comment: The same basic concept applies for addition, subtraction and multiplication--but with caveats. If you subtract 3.333 by 2.222, you have three decimal places of precision in the result--but if you multiply 3.333 by 2.222 you have six decimal places of precision in the final answer. You can use the same little hack to calculate precision, but you may need to total it in a different way depending on the mathematical operator in the expression.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want a rounding kludge, you cannot use floating point numbers and have to find [a decimal arithmetic library.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744099/) Nothing built-in, I am afraid.